# Написать Алгоритм который вычисляет 3 максимальных значения (список не сортирован (сортировки нельзя использовать))

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть Список(Массив) Заполненный Рандомными значениями Диапазон значений от: 0 до 100. Нужно написать алгоритм который выведет топ 3 больших значений (без использования сортировки, разрешено только одно прохождение по массиву[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Comment: 1 .https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

2.https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код текстом. Можно рассчитывать на получение гораздо более качественных ответов, если привести код, с помощью которого участники смогут воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: А если бы было одно макс. значение - как бы вы сделали?

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

arr = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)]

a, b, c = arr[:3]

for i in range(3, len(arr)):
    if arr[i]>=a or arr[i]>=b or arr[i]>=c:
        if a<=b or a<=c:
            a = arr[i]
        else:
            if b<=c:
                b = arr[i]
            else:
                c = arr[i]
print(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import random

array = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10)]
print(array)

def max_ (a):
    max1 = max(array)
    print(max1)
    array.remove(max1)
for i in range(3):
    max_(array)
```

Comment: Разрешено только ОДНО прохождение по массиву

Comment: @Danil пишите комментарии в комментариях, а не вносите правки в ответы.